# Passing through value in href

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

*How do I pass a value through href tag in the XAML of my ASP.NET work?*
I have tried this:

```
 <a href='profile.aspx?ID=<%#HttpContext.Current.Session["id"]%>'>Profile</a>
```

However the URL displays like `"profile.aspx?ID="`

*What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: Have you debugged to see what the variable is get passed to it?

Comment: @Quill Yes the variable is 44

Comment: Did your session timeout by any chance?

Comment: @Quill Nope, it still remains

Comment: You could try making a literal, and building the string in C# and outputting the url to the literal. Other than that, I'd say provide more code.

Comment: "XAML of my ASP.NET work"? Usually for ASP.Net it would be ASPX /WebForms or CSHTML(Razor)/ASP.Net MVC... Clarifying what you mean as "XAML" would be nice.

Comment: @Quill I have tried that, their is no other code to provide? Like the variable is correct it shows 44, seems to me theirs something wrong with the code I initially posted above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your code nugget to work properly with `#`, you need to call the `DataBind` method. Alternatively, you can use the code nugget with `=` and it should work fine for you:-

```
 <a href='profile.aspx?ID=<%= HttpContext.Current.Session["id"]%>'>Profile</a>
```